# How to reposition a floating menu

Tags: html, css, web

how to repostitioin a floating menu here is code. Thanks!, have a cookie!
please could you help me much appreciated for computer science proejct at schoolTY

```html
<style>
  div.floating-menu {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  div.floating-menu a,
  div.floating-menu h3 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
  }
</style>
<div class="floating-menu">
  <h3 style="color: #66FF66">HISTORY OF THE INTERNET</h3>
  <a href="http://www.quackit.com/css/" style="color: #66FF66">PAGE 1</a>
  <a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/" style="color: #66FF66">PAGE 2</a>
  <a href="http://www.quackit.com/javascript/" style="color: #66FF66">PAGE 3</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of info there. Hm, reposition how? The key here is div.floating-menu. You can use top: 100px; left: 100px; to position it 100px from the top left edge. You could also use right: 0; to set it to the right instead.